# ORACLE Doesnt accept variables in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have this code,

```
$head_mark = $_POST["headmark"];
$id = $_POST["headmark_id"];

 $cuttingUpdateParse = oci_parse($conn, "UPDATE FABRICATION SET CUTTING = $cutting_done
                                  WHERE HEAD_MARK = $head_mark AND ID = $id");
```

somehow oracle doesnt want to accept this kind of code. the message i got from firebug is

**warning:**

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "TEST1": invalid identifier in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\update_bar\process_class.php on line 33

Please help me with your suggestion, the data type in associated with `HEAD_MARK` is `VARCHAR2(15)`. I am assuming we need to make some kind of string conversion so that oracle sql can read it.

Comment: The OCI extension supports parameterised statements. Use them. See http://php.net/manual/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Comment: @Daan That's some pretty bad advice

Comment: @Phil true but works, I'm using OCI PDO at mine works awesome.

Comment: @Phil parameterised statements doens't work well with OCI.

Comment: @ponciste Total rubbish. See my answer below

Comment: @Phil I didn't say it's not possible. I said prepared statements are not working properly.

Comment: @ponciste and again, I say *total rubbish*. You show me how they are *"not working properly"* and I'll eat my hat. In my 3 years of working with PHP and Oracle via the OCI extension, I never once had a parameterised statement *not work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should use a prepared statement with parameter binding. This avoids the need to manually quote your values as well as providing a safe means to use them without worrying about SQL injection.

For example...

```
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, 'UPDATE FABRICATION SET CUTTING = :cutting_done
                          WHERE HEAD_MARK = :head_mark AND ID = :id');
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':cutting_done', $cutting_done);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':head_mark', $head_mark);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id);
oci_execute($stmt);
```